# Change bg colour instantly

Tags: javascript, refresh, background-color

I'm trying to make some JavaScript to change the background color of a site instantly according to the hex code in a text box labeled 'color'. It works when I press a submit button but I want it to change itself without the need to submit.

Thanks in advance

```
$(function(){
  setInterval(changeBackground, 1);
});


function changeBackground() {
  // The working function for changing background color.
  document.bgColor = document.getElementById("color").value;
}
```

Comment: [`document.bgColor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/bgColor) is old, really really really old. Use `document.body.style.backgroundColor` instead

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign a `onchange` event listener to your `<input>` as I've done in following code:

```
 document.getElementById('color').addEventListener('change', changeBackground);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input). `addEventListener` lets you react to an event such as clicks, textbox value changes, etc. The `input` event fires every time the user enters something into the element in question.

```js
var colorEl = document.getElementById('color');
colorEl.addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.bgColor = colorEl.value;
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="color" />
```

Pro-tip: `bgColor` isn't the preferred way of doing this anymore. It's been deprecated and is not guaranteed to work in browsers any more. It's much better to use CSS whenever styling things.

```
document.style.backgroundColor = colorEl.value;
```

If you'd rather wait until the user finishes typing then moves the focus elsewhere, you can use the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change).

```js
var colorEl = document.getElementById('color');
colorEl.addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.bgColor = colorEl.value;
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="color" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to watch event key up

```js
function changeBackground() {
  document.bgColor = '#' + document.getElementById("color").value;
}
```

```html
<input id="color" onkeyup="changeBackground()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone.

Cyril Beeckman's suggestion below worked well for me, but I see they will all work. cheers

```js
function changeBackground() {
  document.bgColor = '#' + document.getElementById("color").value;
}
```

```html
<input id="color" onkeyup="changeBackground()" />
```